# Solution of twoTwo riddle on codingBat in Java

Tags: java

The question is about Solving [this](http://codingbat.com/prob/p102145) problem from codingBat in Java.

**Problem Statement:**

*Given an array of ints, return true if every 2 that appears in the array is next to another 2.*

*twoTwo({4, 2, 2, 3}) → true*

*twoTwo({2, 2, 4}) → true*

*twoTwo({2, 2, 4, 2}) → false*

First of all going by the problem statement that *every 2 that appears in the array is next to another 2.*  then

> do you think as suggested the outcome for the first inputs shown above
>   should be true?

***twoTwo({4, 2, 2, 3}) → true***

Because as I see it it the **first 2 itself that appears in the array is next to 4 not 2**

**am I confused or it's a wrongly stated question?** I had to grapple with the problem to somehow get the right code to crack the problem as below but it seems a hotch potch:

```
public boolean twoTwo(int[] nums) {
  if(nums.length==0)
  {
    return true;
   }
   if(nums.length==1)
  {
    return !(nums[0]==2);
   }
   if((nums.length==2))
   {
     if((nums[1]==2)&&(nums[0]==2))
       return true;
       else
     return false;
    }
   for(int i=0;i+2<nums.length;i++)
   {
     if((nums[i]!=2)&&(nums[i+1]==2)&&(nums[i+2]!=2))
      return false;
   }
  if((nums[nums.length-2]!=2)&&(nums[nums.length-1]==2))
    return false;

return true;     
}
```

Any efficient alternate solutions are welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: "is next to" means the 2 can be on either side.  So the question is fine.

Comment: How is it not next to a `2`?

Comment: @DaveNewton because next represents "coming immediately after the present one in order, rank, or space."

Comment: @Anirudh "Next to" denotes (directionless) adjacency. It doesn't state "every 2 is followed by a 2".

Comment: Humm Maybe but it seems a bit baffling.

Comment: @Anirudh It's probably a language barrier thing; as a native English speaker I wouldn't assume "next to" implied only coming before another 2. If it had said something like "the next digit after a 2 must be a 2" then a "direction" is given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I would do it.  It's a bit easier to follow I think:

```
public boolean twoTwo(int[] nums)
{
   for (int i=0; i<nums.length; i++)
   {
      if (nums[i] != 2)
         continue;
      if (i >= 1 && nums[i-1] == 2)
         continue;
      if (i < (nums.length-1) && nums[i+1] == 2)
         continue;
      return false;
   }
   return true;     
}
```

Comment: humm fails in the case twoTwo({2, 2, 4}) and few others.

Comment: I removed my non-working second example. I should have actually tested it before posting. :)

Answer (score 3):

The solution I got to the problem is below:

```
public boolean twoTwo(int[] nums) {
    final int length = nums.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < length;){
        int count = 0;      // Used to count following 2's
        while(i < length && nums[i++] == 2){
            count++;
        }
        if(count == 1){ // No adjacent 2's! Set doesn't work.
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true; // Didn't come across a lone 2
}
```

The way that I handle this, is that I count all the adjacent 2's. If the count is not 1, we are good. This means that there was either no 2 at that index, or a group of 2's was present. This holds, since we traverse the array in a single direction.

A good thing about this solution is that it will work for an array of any size. Note that it would have a linear complexity, even though 2 loops are present. They both just traverse using the same index value, only ever sweeping over the array once.

If at any time we find a 2, then check the following only to find there are 0 following 2's (denoted by `count`), we return false.

Comment: Well most solutions are working for any length of the array umm lil sceptical about using 2 loops performance wise. Not a bad way of attacking the problem.

Comment: @Anirudh I do address the added complexity for the two loops, it is no extra operations. Best case is O(1) - worst is O(n) - average is O(n). This is no more complex than any other method of doing this problem here.

Comment: @Anirudh Note that the inner loop increments the same index as the outer loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
public boolean twoTwo(int[] nums) {

  for (int i=0; i<nums.length; i++) {

    if(nums[i] == 2) {                             //If current number is 2
      if (
         // if prev or next is not 2 return true

         !(i-1>=0 && nums[i-1] == 2) &&           
         !(i+1<nums.length && nums[i+1] == 2)

         )  {   return false; }
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

For the sake of simplicity and clean code, this code forces the check

> `i-1>=0` and `i+1<nums.length` in every iteration.

This can be avoided by iterating from `(1...nums.length-1)` and checking the edge cases separately.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I came up with a new solution. Short, and with no complicated conditionals.

```
public boolean twoTwo(int[] nums) {
  int position = -2;
  boolean result = true;

  for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    if (nums[i] == 2) {
      result = position == i - 1;
      position = i;
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Next to means either before or after. Loop through each number and check the values before and after to see if there's an adjacent 2. The special cases are when you're checking the 1st and last element because there won't be an element before or after to check.

```
public boolean twoTwo(int[] nums) {

    if(nums.length == 1 && nums[0] == 2)
        return false;

    for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if(nums[i] == 2) {
            if(i == 0) { // check the next element
                if(nums[i+1] != 2)
                    return false;
            }
            else if(i == (nums.length - 1)) { // check the previous element
                if(nums[i-1] != 2)
                    return false;
            }
            else { // check both
                if(nums[i+1] != 2 && nums[i-1] != 2)
                    return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here is mine solution to two two's problem](https://github.com/spookiecookie/codingbatsolutions/blob/master/codingbat/array2/TwoTwo.java). I think my solution is clear i.e. understandable.

```
package codingbat.array2;

public class TwoTwo
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    }

    public boolean twoTwo(int[] nums) 
    {
        boolean twoTwo = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
        {   
            if (2 == nums[i])
            {
                if (i > 0 && 2 == nums[i - 1]
                 || nums.length > i+1 && 2 == nums[i+1])
                {   
                    twoTwo = true;   
                    i++;                
                } 
                else
                {
                    twoTwo = false;
                    break;
                }          
            }
        }  

        return twoTwo;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean twoTwo(int[] nums) {
  for(int i = 0 ; i < nums.length; i++ ) {
     int count = 0;
     if(nums[i] == 2 ) {

        while(i+1 < nums.length &&  nums[i+1] == 2 ) {
          count ++;
          i++;
        }

        if (count == 0 ) {
          return false;
        }
     }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean twoTwo(int[] nums) {
  for(int i = 0;i<nums.length;i++)
    if(nums[i]==2 && !isTwoBeforeOrAfter(nums,i))
      return false;
  return true;
}

private boolean isTwoBeforeOrAfter(int[] nums,int i){
  return i+1<nums.length && nums[i+1]==2 || i-1>=0 && nums[i-1]==2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean twoTwo(int[] nums) {

    float two = 0;
    double count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {

        if (i < nums.length - 2 && nums[i] == 2 && nums[i + 1] == 2 && nums[i + 2] == 2) {
            return true;
        }

        if (i < nums.length - 1 && nums[i] == 2 && nums[i + 1] == 2) {
            count++; //count the pair
        }

        if (nums[i] == 2) {
            two++;
        }
    }
    return ((count * 2) == two);
   //each pair contain 2 ,two"s .so pair*2=total two counts
   //count
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean twoTwo(int[] nums) {
  boolean two = false;
  boolean result = true;

  for (int i=0; i<nums.length; i++) {
    if (nums[i] == 2) {
      if (two) {
        result = true;
      } else {
        result = false;
      }
    two = true;
    } else {
      two = false;
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution. Enjoy.

```
public boolean twoTwo(int[] nums) 
    {
      //If the length is 2 or more
      if (nums.length >= 2)
      {
        //If the last char is a 2, but the one before it is not a char, we return false;
        if (nums[nums.length - 1] == 2 && nums[nums.length - 2] != 2)
        {
          return false;
        }
        //If larger than three, we create a for loop to test if we have any 2s that are alone.
        if (nums.length >= 3)
        {
          for (int i = 1; i < nums.length-1; i++)
          {
            //If we find a two that is alone, we return false;
            if ((nums[i] == 2) && (nums[i-1] != 2 && nums[i+1] != 2))
            {
              return false;
            }
          }
        }
        //If we don't return false, we return true;
        return true;
      }
      //If we have less than two characters, we return true if the length is 0, or \
      //One the one number there is not a 2.
      else
      {
        return ((nums.length == 0) || !(nums[0] == 2));
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean twoTwo(int[] nums) {
  int len = nums.length;
  Boolean check = false;
  int  count = 0;

  for(int i=0; i<len ; i++){
    if(nums[i]==2){
      count++;
      if((i<len-1 && nums[i+1]==2) || (i>0 && nums[i-1]==2)) check = true;
      else check = false;
    }
  }

  if(count==0) check = true;  
 return check;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
public boolean twoTwo(int[] nums) {
  int count = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
    if (nums[i] == 2) count++;
    else if (count == 1) return false;
    else count = 0;
  return count != 1;
}
```

Every time we encounter a `2`, we increase the counter of consecutive `2`s.

When it's not a `2` — but the counter indicates that there was a single `2` before it —, we know we've found a lonely `2`.

Otherwise the search continues, resetting the `2`-counter.

Comment: You possibly might want to add a little bit of explanation to that answer, since code-only answers are mostly looked down upon.

Answer (score 0):

easy to understand)

```
static boolean twoTwo(int[] nums) {
    int len = nums.length;
    boolean result = true;
    boolean found = false;

    for(int i=0; i<len; i++){
        //if it not 2, no meaning to go true other if-s
        if(nums[i] !=2) {found = false; continue;}
        // if current element is 2 and found is true(last element is 2)
        if(nums[i] ==2 && found) result = true;
        // if current element is 2, but last element not
        if(nums[i] ==2 && !found){
            found = true;
            result = false;
        }

    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be easier to follow if the other suggestions confuse you..

```
public boolean twoTwo(int[] nums) {
  int len = nums.length;
  if(len == 0) return true;   // no 2's to worry about
  if(len == 1) return nums[0] != 2;   // make sure it's not a single 2

  for(int i = 1; i < len -1; i++){    // loop for each except edge cases
    if(nums[i] == 2 && nums[i-1] != 2 && nums[i+1] != 2) return false;  // check surrounding
  }

  if(nums[len - 1] == 2) return nums[len - 2] == 2; //if last num is 2 check for 2 before it
  return true;  // made it here it's true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

that one was tough for me... here's mine:

```
public boolean twoTwo(int[] nums) {

  boolean two = false, res = true;

  for (int i : nums) {
    if (i == 2) {
      if (two)
        res = true;
      else {
        two = true;
        res = false;
      }
    } else {
      two = false;
    }
  }

  return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One more alternative. Here is the main idea:

1. Convert array into String. Add a character different from "2" at the beginning and end of the string, to avoid going out of bounds.
2. Look for standalone "2" - if element of the string is equal to 2, check whether chars immediately before and after are also equal to "2". If they are it means that not all "2" are adjacent, and therefore method returns false.

   ```
    public boolean twoTwo(int[] nums) {

        // convert array to string
        String text = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            text += String.valueOf(nums[i]);
        }

        text = " " + text + " ";

        // find standalone "2"
        for (int i = 1; i < text.length() - 1; i++) {
            if (text.charAt(i) == '2' && text.charAt(i - 1) != '2' && text.charAt(i + 1) 
        != '2') {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
   ```